# Errors when defining a subclass method for a final method

Tags: php, inheritance

I'm just getting to grips with OOP PHP and while I have understood it ok, I'm having some trouble with the `final` keyword. `Final`, the book says, stops the subclass method, overriding the superclass method. Below I've tried it and my IDE is showing some errors and it doesn't work. I have looked and looked but the book says this should envoke the superclass method not the subclass.

```
$object=new userprofile();
$object->name="Mike";
$object->age=22;
$object->sex="Male";

//2 properties of subclass
$object->email="username@domain.com";
$object->website="http://domain.com";

echo $object->get_name(); //method call

class user{
    public $name, $age, $sex;

    final function get_name(){
        return "Not overriden";
    }
}

class userprofile extends user{
    public $email,$website;

    function get_name(){
        return $this->website;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run the script, what errors do you get?

Comment: Hi, Juhana.. Fatal error: Cannot override final method user::get_name() in H:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_testers\objects_OOP\object_inheritence.php on line 41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't define a method that would override a method that's been tagged final. You aren't even allowed to try (and why would you, because the new method wouldn't have any effect).

See also the [documentation for the final keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) which describes this in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you answered yourself. By defining the `final` keyword on the base class you cannot override it in a child class. Remove the `final` keyword in order to override it.

Comment: What it means is that the child class (`userprofile`) cannot override a parent (`user`) method that has a `final` keyword attached. It's used to give the parent class control over what a child class can and cannot override. Removing the method from the subclass entirely will envoke the parent class' method.